# Newtonsoft.Json DeserializeObject passing null for guid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a class that is used to represent an identity, it contains a value of string.

I then have another class that is used to represent an event, this includes an identity object, and a string name.

I can serialize from object to JSON string fine, I get the string:

`{"Id":{"Value":"2e4146c2-66c9-4637-8936-29ccfc5df638"},"Name":"Jon Doe"}`

However when I go from the above JSON to object, in the MyIdentity constructor the string identityValue is passed in as `"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"`.

I have also tried providing two constructors for MyIdentity, one for string, and one for Guid, but same result. The idea behind this is to store the data as a string, but to remember we can be cast to a Guid if required (since identities will either be formed by a string or by a Guid).

```
public class MyEntityId : MyIdentity
{
    public MyEntityId(Guid identityValue)
        : base(identityValue)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MyIdentity
{
    protected readonly bool convertableAsGuid;
    protected readonly string value;

    public string Value { get { return this.value; } }

    public MyIdentity(string identityValue)
    {
        this.value = identityValue;

        Guid guid;
        if(Guid.TryParse(identityValue, out guid)==false)
            this.convertableAsGuid = false;
    }

    public MyIdentity(Guid identityValue)
    {
        this.value = identityValue.ToString();
        this.convertableAsGuid = true;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var evnt = new MyEvent(new MyEntityId(Guid.NewGuid()), "Jon Doe");

    var eventHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"EventClrTypeName", evnt.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName}
    };
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
    var metadata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventHeaders, serializerSettings));
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evnt, serializerSettings));
    string dataAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    var eventClrTypeName = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(metadata)).Property("EventClrTypeName").Value;
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataAsString, Type.GetType((string)eventClrTypeName));
    // stepping through the above, a zero initialised GUID string is passed in to MyIdentity constructor
}
```

As @hvd has kindly commented, it seems to be the Value only has a get property, if i add a set property also then it works (so I believe the constructor string value is not actually being used). The reason I don't want to put a setter on the identity is for programming design, it is an identity and should not be changed once created.

I can live with a public get and protected set on the property, I have tried the keyword `[JsonProperty]` and it works... however I don't want to decorate my domain objects with those attributes - is there another way?

Comment: The problem is probably that the `Value` property has no setter and cannot be mapped to the constructor argument, but that doesn't really help you fix it.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my situation I was getting an every-GUID-becomes-an-empty-GUID behavior with a protected property setter.  That's how I arrived at this question.  I ended up having to turn mine into a full public property, which I also don't like from an architectural standpoint but, as a practical matter, isn't too bad in my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have a problem initializing the `Guid` on deserialization and you don't want to create a setter or use attributes for successful deserialization. Please note that I changed your `MyIdentity` class by removing the constructor that accepted `Guid` parameter since it's not necessary, changed the parsing of `Guid` logic since it would have never initialize the `convertableAsGuid` property correctly and created `MyEvent` class since you didn't post it on your question. Also I created the `MyCustomConverter` class which is used during the deserialization. Here are the classes:

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (MyEvent);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        existingValue = new MyEvent(new MyEntityId(jObject["Id"]["Value"].ToString()), jObject["Name"].ToString());

        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyEvent
{
    public MyEntityId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyEvent(MyEntityId id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class MyEntityId : MyIdentity
{
    public MyEntityId(string identityValue)
        : base(identityValue)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MyIdentity
{
    protected readonly bool convertableAsGuid;
    protected readonly string value;

    public string Value { get { return this.value; } }

    public MyIdentity(string identityValue)
    {
        this.value = identityValue;

        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParse(identityValue, out guid))
            this.convertableAsGuid = true;
    }
}
```

And here is the serialization and deserialization logic:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var evnt = new MyEvent(new MyEntityId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), "Jon Doe");

    var eventHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"EventClrTypeName", evnt.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName}
        };
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
    var metadata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventHeaders, serializerSettings));
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evnt, serializerSettings));
    string dataAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    var eventClrTypeName = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(metadata)).Property("EventClrTypeName").Value;
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEvent>(dataAsString, new JsonConverter[] {new MyCustomConverter()});
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/asRtEI